# Did Darth Maul think that Senator Palpatine would reveal himself to the Jedi?

Tags: star-wars, darth-sidious, the-phantom-menace, darth-maul

In *The Phantom Menace*, Darth Maul is speaking with Palpatine on Coruscant. During the exchange, Darth Maul says:

> At last we will reveal ourselves to the Jedi.  At last we will have revenge.

Did Darth Maul think that Senator Palpatine would reveal himself to the Jedi?

Comment: This would benefit from naming who said this, to whom, and when.

Comment: When I read this question, I get this image in my mind of Senator Palpatine going up to the Jedi Temple, dropping all his clothes, and revealing himself to the Jedi.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Probably not

Examining the context in the script of *The Phantom Menace* makes things a little more clear:

> DARTH MAUL : Tatooine is sparsely populated. If the trace was correct,
>   I will find them quickly, Master.
>
> DARTH SIDIOUS : Move against the Jedi first…you will then have no
>   difficulty taking the Queen back to Naboo, where she will sign the
>   treaty.
>
> DARTH MAUL : At last we will reveal ourselves to the Jedi. At last we
>   will have revenge.
>
> DARTH SIDIOUS : You have been well trained, my young apprentice, they
>   will be no match for you. It is too late for them to stop us now.
>   Everything is going as planned. The Republic will soon be in my
>   command.

Darth Maul is saying this directly after Sidious has told him to move against the Jedi, suggesting that he sees this as revealing themselves to the Jedi. It’s more the revelation of the Sith as a whole, rather than the specific revelation of Sidious’s existence, that Maul intends. And indeed, after fighting Maul the Jedi do realize that the Sith are active once more.

Comment: `Reveal` here refers to the fact that since the time of Darth Bane, the Sith have hidden their existence from the Jedi. The Jedi believing that there were no more Sith was crucial to the Sith Grand Plan. Given that a move against the queen who was under protection of 2 Jedi would only be possible if Maul made full use of his force powers he simply wanted to make sure that this `revealing` of a live Sith was okay with his master's plans

Answer (score 9):

I'm not aware of any canon explanation in more detail, but at this stage remember that the Jedi Order thought the Sith were extinct, but knew of the Rule of Two. Because of this, Darth Maul revealing himself did in fact cause the Jedi to deduce that there must be two Sith. In this light it could easily be interpreted as just revealing their existence, rather than identity.

Comment: That is essentially what I was thinking as soon as I saw the question. I took it for granted all along that Maul basically meant: "At last we will let the Jedi know that the Sith are still around, and actively plotting against them. They've scarcely heard from us in centuries; they probably hope we've died out, or are hiding in terror, or something!" He didn't mean: "And of course you will walk up to the Jedi Temple and tell them your whole life story so that they **know** you are a Sith Lord!"

Comment: Yes, Maul doesn't mean that Palpatine will reveal himself to the Jedi, but the Sith will reveal themselves. Like "Hey guys, Sith are coming !"

Answer (score 0):

Due to the fact that the **jedi** want the **siths** to be extincted. The with aren't going to show themselves to the Jedi as they are not yet a match for them. But there might be that they confront the Jedi if they have enough power. Therefore the with aren't going to confront the jedi

Comment: Does this answer the question?

Comment: I have edited my answer

Comment: So, does Darth Maul expect Palpatine to reveal himself? What did he mean when he said that the Sith would reveal themselves to the Jedi?